# handle in win32 sdk .how to declare handle in c#

Tags: c#, winapi

handle in win32 sdk .how to declare handle in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows handle is an IntPtr in C#.

If your code created the handle then you should use one of the SafeHandle derived classes to wrap it so it is guaranteed to be released.  Avoids having to write a finalizer.